# Why is != not working? how to compare with null values?

Tags: postgresql

I am having a hard time understanding why the following query is not working?

`select id,sold_dealer_id from myi_corporate where sold_dealer_id != 36;`

When I do the following I am getting the result

`select id,sold_dealer_id from myi_corporate where sold_dealer_id = 36;`

However for `!=` I am not getting the opposite results.

I am returning to psql after a long time after using MongoDB and might have forgotten the basics. Any suggestion is much appreciated

Comment: Any NULL values in that column? You might want to try `where sold_dealer_id != 36` or sol_dealer_id is null` - or simplified to `where sold_dealer_id is distinct from 36`

Comment: all the remaining values are NULL, i just updated one row to have value '36'

Comment: Using `IS NULL` solves the problem, but I am trying to get values that are not  `!= 36`, any suggestion is much appreciated, but i now know the cause is `NULL` Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks a lot `select * from myi_corporate where sold_dealer_id is distinct from 36` got the query worrking :)

Comment: Remember that SQL has tristate logic: `true`, `false`, and `null`. Use `is null` or `is distinct from` when comparing against `null`.

Comment: `OR IS NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `!=` rather than the SQL standard operator `<>`, but I recommend using the latter. That has no influence on your problem though.

Your table must contain some NULL values in `sold_dealer_id`.

Now `NULL = 36` is not true, but `NULL <> 36` is **also** not true, so such lines are excluded from both query results.

You can use `sold_dealer_id IS DISTINCT FROM 36` to get the opposite of `sold_dealer_id = 36`. That operator will treat NULL values as if they were normal values.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! 
Yes the comparison is with `NULL = 36` currently and seems fair, is there a correct way to compare with NULL as my query depends on using an `id` and want to fetch other rows that are `sold_dealer_id !=  <NUMBERr>`

Comment: I have added a way to do that to the answer.

Comment: You can also add `or sold_dealer IS NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the results because a null value will never match anything else. If you know you are going to have null values I would also exclude those from the result.

```
select id,
       sold_dealer_id 
from   myi_corporate 
where  sold_dealer_id = 36
and    sold_dealer_id is not null;


select id,
       sold_dealer_id 
from   myi_corporate 
where  sold_dealer_id != 36
and    sold_dealer_id is not null;
```

You can also do a quick search to find any with a null value

```
select id,
       sold_dealer_id 
from   myi_corporate 
where  sold_dealer_id is null;
```

Answer (score -3):

By using correct postgres-Syntax...

```
select id,sold_dealer_id from myi_corporate where NOT (sold_dealer_id = 36);
```

Postgres is a database, not a c-family programming language

https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/not.php with some examples

Comment: I tried that, did not work! Thanks though :). I am getting 195 result for a select query but no luck with NOT or !=

Comment: FYI, it is a foriegn key, does it make a difference ?

Comment: Okay turns out something I am doing is wrong, I tried with a string field example 
`select * from myi_corporate where NOT (company_reg_id = '9990000000000');` which seems to work but for that field which is an integer and a foreign key its not working , any solutions?

Comment: Although the SQL standard defines `<>` as the "not equals" operator, Postgres does support using `!=`  as well. Changing the condition to a negated equals condition won't change a thing. `NOT (sold_dealer_id = 36)`  is the same as `sold_dealer_id <> 36` which is the same as `(sold_dealer_id != 36`